# android push notification sound

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, push

i have small android project
and this is my notifications code

```
public class MyfirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("FCM NOTIFICATION");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
 }
}
```

but when the notification come there is no sound 
any help please thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notifysound);
notificationBuilder.setSound(sound);
```

and put notifysound into raw folder.

Comment: i have this error cannot resolve symbol uri and this is image for that error https://imgur.com/zjzEILU

Comment: please import Uri. Or if you use android studio simply mouse click on Uri and press Alt+Enter

Comment: its ok with Uri now but its not with cannot resolve symbol 'raw'

Comment: I think you can't create raw folder.Please create a raw folder under res folder and paste your sound clip on it. 
how to create a raw folder:
https://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/create-raw-folder-android-studio.html